# Most pythonic way to super parent class and pass class variables

Tags: python, class, super

I have a parent class and a child class. The parent class needs some predefined class variables to run `call()`. The objects are not defined in the child class.

**Question:** What is the most pythonic way to pass the variables when calling `super()` **without changing the parent class**.

Example:

```
class Parent:
  def __init__(self):
    self.my_var = 0

  def call(self):
    return self.my_var + 1

class Child(Parent):
  def __init__(self):
    self.different_var = 1

  def call(self):
    my_var = 0
    super().__call__() # What is the most pythonic way of performing this line
```

I know I could just make `my_var` in the child class a class object and it would work, but there must be a better. If not that would be an acceptable answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version is just a mixin. You have to `__init__` the `super`.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_var = 0

    def call(self):
        return self.my_var + 1

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    #init super
        self.different_var = 1

    def call(self):
        self.my_var = 50
        return super().call() #return call() from super
        
c = Child()
print(c.call()) #51
```

Comment: It seems like `super().__init__()` is the right thing here to me.

Comment: @MarkMeyer ~ Why? What if it was `class Child(Parent, Uncle)` then which one is the `super`?

Comment: I guess if that were possible, I would expect the classes to be designed around MRO in which case your would *definitely* not want to hard code the name.

Comment: @MarkMeyer It's entirely possible. One could absolutely be a mixin.

Comment: @michealguidry ... if you’re not sure which is the `super` in your `__init__` then you won’t be in your `call` method either

Comment: @donkopotamus `super().__init__()` can straight up break your code, especially when dealing with `tkinter`, for instance. Ambiguity is never the answer for initialization.

Comment: You’re possibly missing my point ... if you think an mro based super chain will break your `__init__` then it’s going to break your `call` as well ... choose one or the other.

Comment: That's why you get specific. `Parent` is definitely the `super` and it would remain the `super` even if I added `Uncle`, `Cousin`, `Grandma` and `ThirdWife`. ;)

Comment: @michaelguidry ... it’s perfectly possible that `super().call()` is **not** immediately calling `Parent` in such a multiple inheritance framework.  However I think we’re misunderstanding each other.

Comment: @donkopotamus ~ I stand corrected. The first member is the `super`. I just made an example for myself and `Child(Uncle, Parent)` actually made `Uncle` the `super` regardless of the `Parent.__init__(self)`. I flipped them and `Parent` became the `super` again. Whattayaknow. I'll change my answer to `super().__init__()` in recognition. I believe I understand you, just maybe not as deeply as required.